# Asynchronous calls with AjaxPro

Tags: asynchronous, ajaxpro

I have been working with synchronous calls in AjaxPro, and I am now looking into asynchronous calls. I have been looking at the example [Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/ajaxpro@googlegroups.com/msg01801.html)

My question is : How do I pass variables to my ajaxpro method?

I would like to add some properties to the AjaxMethod MyMethod :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callback(res) {
    alert(res.value);
}
function invokeMyMethod() {
    Namespace.Classname.MyMethod(callback);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server-side method will look like this:

```
public void MyMethod(int param1, string param2, ...)
```

You need to call this from the client like so:

```
Namespace.Classname.MyMethod(param1, param2, callback);
```

That should do it.